# return back()->withInput($request->input()) throws The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-6.2

I am getting this error **"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."** if there are any errors in a form.

I can successfully post to my form but it throws during the return process.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/services/book/hotel', 'HotelController@showbook');
Route::post('/services/book/hotelroom', 'HotelController@book');
```

book function is fairly lengthy but ends in

```
    if($responseSuccess){
        $error = [];
        $bookingDetail = json_decode($response['BookingDetail']);

        return Redirect::to(url('my-account'));
    } else {
        $error = $response['message'];
        $hotel = [];

        session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 
        session()->flash('message', $error); 

    // dd(__method__.'::'.__line__,get_defined_vars(),$request->input());
        return back()->withInput($request->input());
    }
```

if I uncomment the `dd` I get see that everything looks like I would expect as far as the errors and the inputs but when I hit the return I see.  What am I doing wrong?

I have read throught dozens of articles here on slack and other sites that talk about the "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." but none of them seem to have the issue when "returning `back`"

[image]

I am using PHP 7.2 and Laravel/framework 6.2

[image]

If I try to change the form from a post to a get I recieve this error because there is a lot of data being passed. And the client prefers this in a post so it can't be bookmarked or emailed.

[image]

This page is passing a lot of "hidden" variables and I want to be able to display error if needed and still have the variables.  Is that not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307):

```php
return back(307)->withInput();
```

**Better solution:**

Instead of changing the `<form>` action attribute from `POST` to `GET`, you need to change the page that shows the form:

```php
Route::get('/services/book/hotel', 'HotelController@showbook');
Route::post('/services/book/hotelroom', 'HotelController@book');
```

Comment: the issue with that is that I have 3 pages that post to the next, continually adding data to the next form.  One of the hidden inputs contains a very large encrypted field that is a lot of data.  POSTing from one form to the next works but if it passed in a GET it exceeds the limit of a url string.

Comment: you can store the forms in session then merge them in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

The `back()` helper is a redirect to a page using the `GET` method.
If it is trying to `GET` `/services/book/hotel` or `/services/book/hotelroom` it will fail.

What is the url of the page that shows the form?

Comment: Is there a helper that can redirect to a POST page? Or how do I redirect to a POST form.

Comment: @Lance you cannot redirect to a POST page. Redirects are GET requests only. Perhaps you should use the validator to send error messages back to the page instead of doing a redirect. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: @Lance based on your updated question. You don't want to change the actual data being passed as a get request but the page they are coming from. Based on your routes it looks like /services/book/hotel needs to change to Route::get('/services/book/hotel', 'HotelController@showbook')

Comment: Unfortunately the form is not a "typical" validation as the form uses an apis to see if credit cards are processed successfully and if the room has been booked in the last few minutes and items like that which would take the entire function and make it into a validation.

Comment: @Lance perhaps the final request should be an ajax request? Submit via ajax and if successful, redirect to the success page, otherwise handle errors.